# Обрезать строку без HTML-тегов

Tags: php

Нужно перед записью в базу данных на сервере проверить длину строки и, если она превышает максимальную, обрезать. Разумеется, длина строки должна браться без учета HTML-тегов, а при обрезке все теги должны быть закрыты. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Задача становится заметно веселее, когда на вход может поступить некорректный HTML...

Answer (score 2):

```
function cutStr($str, $length=50, $postfix='...')
{
    if ( strlen($str) <= $length)
        return $str;

    $temp = substr($str, 0, $length);
    return substr($temp, 0, strrpos($temp, ' ') ) . $postfix;
}
```

Параметры:

- $str - исходная строка
- $length - сколько символов оставить
- $postfix - что писать в конце